# Is it possible to keep rotation values relative to the north in line pattern fill when making a print layout with rotation in map?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, style, angles

I have a polygon that I am displaying with Line pattern fill.

The orientations of the pattern fill is set by an attribute in the file with the value of the angle rotation.

I am creating a print layout of the map and I introduced a rotation of the map to have a better display.

The pattern fill of the polygon file keeps the same absolute rotation value and does not rotate with the layout.

For the moment, the only solution that I am thinking of after trying a couple of options is to create another field with adjusted orientation value angle_layout which would not show correctly the lines on the canvas but would give me the correct orientation in the print layout.

Does anyone know if there is another solution to that problem?

Before rotation in print layout

[image]

After rotation in print layout

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use the `Rotation` field of the Map item (not the `Map rotation` in the main properties)

This will keep the Lines oriented properly but the whole frame is rotated.
[image]

To frame it properly again:

- expand the Map item size so that it covers the whole layout,
- draw a Rectangle item where you want to frame the map,
- go to the map `Clipping settings` and `clip to item` with the Rectangle as a mask

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great! thank you for the answer, that is exactly what I was looking for...I never used the clipping setting before.